# Is the quantum vacuum timeless?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vacuum

I recently heard that the quantum vacuum is timeless because it lacks a time arrow
Since the time arrow is determined by the interaction of particles and in quantum vacuum there are no particles that means that there are no time is quantum vacuum?
Making the virtual particles also timeless

Comment: where did you hear this?

Comment: Not having a time arrow is not equal to being timeless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mauricio said, not having a time arrow is different from being timeless. Fields still change with time, but there is no obvious distinction between past and future. Imagine you are watching a regular movie, you can easily tell if the movie is being played forward or backwards. If the movie were instead white noise, then there would be no way for you to tell if the movie is being played forward or backwards. White noise does not have an arrow of time.

Comment: So that means that time is independent of matter? And for example in a vacuum universe there will be also time if we can somehow observe that universe?, Thanks I know that i was wrong then

Comment: Yes, there could be just fluctuating fields.